# Wix v3 Setting Install Folder according Property given in command line

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to change the installation location according to condition.
If property DRIVE was provided in the installation command line, I would like to perform :

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDERA" Name="My Program Files">
      <Directory Id="KUKU" Name="KUKU"  >
         <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="BuiltInPropertiesExample"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

If property DRIVE was NOT provided (in the installation command line), I would like to perform :

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="BuiltInPropertiesExample"/>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

How do I perform such installation ?

Comment: is DRIVE custom public property defined or You mean standard ROOTDRIVE property?

Comment: @VivekJaiswal I do not mean to the standard ROOTDRIVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="BuiltInPropertiesExample" />
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<SetDirectory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[LOCATION]" Sequence="execute" >
  <![CDATA[NOT Installed OR LOCATION]]>
</SetDirectory >
```

when executing

```
msiexec /i BuiltInPropertiesExample.msi  LOCATION=D:\MyProduct\
```

the tool is installed D:\MyProduct\

When executing

```
msiexec /i BuiltInPropertiesExample.msi
```

the tool is installed C:\Program Files\